# Salt-api use other matching method other then glob

Tags: salt-stack

By default, salt-api uses glob method to match target minion. Is it possible to use other way(maybe grains, pcre and so on) to find minions.

I tried to pass tgt_type to salt-api, but it didn't work.

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -d username='user' -d password='pwd' -d eauth='pam' -d fun='test.ping' -d tgt='127.0.0.1' -d client='local' -d tgt_type='ipcidr' localhost:8000/run
```

Comment: Finally, I got the answer from the salt source code `client/__init__.py`. The cmd funciton accept `expr_form` parameter to indicate matching type. For eaxmple:     `curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" -d username='user' -d password='pwd' -d eauth='pam' -d fun='test.ping' -d tgt='127.0.0.1' -d client='local' -d expr_form='ipcidr' localhost:8000/run`

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just noticed you answered your own question right after posting below. Glad you figured it out! We should find a way to make that bit of information more obvious in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expr_form` is the option you're looking for.

`expr_form='ipcidr'`

This is found quite often in various parts of Salt.

Here's a legend with the different types of matching in Salt:
http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html

Comment: Thank you all the same. I can't find expr_form parameter in the doc. So I try to find it in the source code! -_-

Comment: I just searched that link you posted and I can't find the words "ipcidr" on there anywhere!  Is there some documentation that decodes what salt-api is expecting and translates it into things like "grains" or "ip address" or something like that?  I'd like to target something by grain and this answer helps me know that I need to pass something to expr_form but I have no idea what.

Comment: to target a grain, using expr_form='grain' worked, then I can target a grain called 'mygrain' with a value of 'derp' by using tgt='mygrain:derp'

Answer (score 3):

`tgt_type` should work with latest versions of Salt API. As referred to as the type of `tgt` (Salt target matcher for minions).

Starting from version 2017.7.0, `expr_form` has been renamed to `tgt_type`.

`tgt_type` can be one of the following:

- `glob` - Bash glob completion - Default
- `pcre` - Perl style regular expression
- `list` - Python list of hosts
- `grain` - Match based on a grain comparison
- `grain_pcre` - Grain comparison with a regex
- `pillar` - Pillar data comparison
- `pillar_pcre` - Pillar data comparison with a regex
- `nodegroup` - Match on nodegroup
- `range` - Use a Range server for matching
- `compound` - Pass a compound match string
- `ipcidr` - Match based on Subnet (CIDR notation) or IPv4 address.

---

For more information, please refer official client function documentation:

- https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/clients